# int object not callable error (sum of multiples)

Tags: python-2.7

I am writing a program to print the sum of multiple of `3` or `5` less than `1000`. I am using an arithmetic progression to do it. My code is:

```
def multiple(x,y):
    a=(1000-(1000%x) - x)/x +1
    b=(995-y)/y +1
    c=(1000-(1000%x*y)-x*y)/x*y +1
    Sa=int(a/2(2*x+(a-1)*a))
    Sb=b/2(2*y+(b-1)*b)
    Sc=c/2(2*x*y+(c-1)*x*y)
    Sd=Sa+Sb-Sc
    print Sd
```

When I call the function I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\swampy-2.1.7\MULTIPLE.py", line 23, in multiple
    Sa=int(a/2(2*x+(a-1)*a))
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Please point out the mistake in my code. Thanks.

P.S. Please forgive my "art" of question asking. I am new to Python and StackOverflow, so please bear with me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Sa=int(a/2(2*x+(a-1)*a))` you forgot a `*` to multiply between `a/2` and `(2*x+(a-1)*a)` You should have `Sa=int(a/2*(2*x+(a-1)*a))`.

Also, the same on `Sb` and `Sc`.